# I want to understand which line of code outputs **none** in the function

Tags: python, function

The last line of the output is **none** can someone explain why pls

```
def just_lyrics():
    print ("i am a bad coder")
    print (" i keep trying to learn everday")
    

def double_lyrics():
    just_lyrics()
    just_lyrics()
    just_lyrics()
print(double_lyrics())
```

output

```
i am a bad coder
 i keep trying to learn everday
i am a bad coder
 i keep trying to learn everday
i am a bad coder
 i keep trying to learn everday
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
print(double_lyrics())
```

Prints `None` because the function returns nothing