# Gets an extra “None” after “ word found” why?

Tags: python

```py
text = input()
word = input()

def search(tx, wd):
    if wd in tx:
        print("Word found")
    else:
        print("Word not found")   
    
print(search(text, word))
```

Comment: `search` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Very similar to this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900472/i-want-to-understand-which-line-of-code-outputs-none-in-the-function

Answer (score 4):

`search` does not return anything, so when you try to print a call to `search` it prints `None`. You can just remove the last print function and call `search`

```py
print(search(text,word)) # will print None

search(text,word) # will print "Word found" or "Word not found", no need to print again.
```

Comment: Good answer, except that `search` returns the object `None`. You can't return nothing, `None` is the closest you get.